# how to save this vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to know how I can define vector variables to save output of this code in vector?

```
/*what should be here?*/=agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
```

`GetcloseTeammateToTeammate` is defined as:

```
const std::vector<Unum> & GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(Unum i) 
{   
  Assert(i > 0); return GetCloseTeammateToPlayer(i); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must be missing something here.  Is it not simply this:

```
const std::vector<Unum> &my_vector = agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
```

Comment: This way, you just save the reference. If the vector changes, your variable changes.

Comment: thanks,but compiler says warning: unused variable ‘my_vector’  what should i do?

Comment: @arash: Use the variable somewhere!  You'll get the same warning if you do `int i = 0;` if you don't then use `i` for something.

Comment: thanks,just another simple question,now how can i print the output of that?

Comment: It depends what `Unum` is.  Assuming you can print an `Unum`, you can iterate through as: `for (i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++) { std::cout << my_vector[i] << "\n"; }`.  There are other, more STL-like, ways of doing this, but that's a start.

Answer (score 5):

`GetCloseTeammateToTeammate` returns a reference to a constant vector.

Simply use:

```
const std::vector<Unum>& x = agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
```

to get the reference. Note that you can only call const member functions of vector.

To get a copy of the vector, do:

```
std::vector<Unum> x = agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
```

Only copy if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different options there, depending on what you actually want. If you only intend to do some processing on the given vector in the short term, (and assuming single threaded execution and a couple other considerations) you can just keep the reference:

```
std::vector<Unum> const & v = agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
for ( std::vector<Unum>::const_iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it )
{
    // do something
}
```

If what you want is to save a copy of the vector so that at a later time you can check for changes, or you want to use the vector as it is now without any later changes (note that this is not entailing thread safety!), just copy it:

```
std::vector<Unum> copy = agent.GetInfoState().GetPositionInfo().GetCloseTeammateToTeammate(2);
```

Comment: thanks,just another simple question,now how can i print the output of that?

Comment: Assuming that you overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&,Unum)`, you can just do: `std::copy( copy.begin(), copy.end(), std::ostream_iterator( std::cout, " " ) );` or alternatively roll your own loop.